# What is the passage of time?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, phrases, phrase-meaning, phrase-origin

Regarding the term/phrase *the passage of time*: Is it simply referring to time *pass*ing (i.e. moving forward / passing by)? A metaphor to invoke imagery of a passageway (path, tunnel, channel, corridor, etc.)? Or the process of transition from one state to another (past→present→future)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's more in the sense of something passing like wind or water. It passes (verb) in a continuous flow from future to the "instant of the present" and then on to the past. Of course that is also imagery, but it is not a noun "passage" like a tunnel or hallway. It is an action.